# T-SQL: Need help understanding 'Strange' SQL in Where Clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following code in the Where Clause of an otherwise straightforward Query that I do not understand and would appreciate help with:

```
    ... AND  --Filter on StoreID
(
('545' IS NOT NULL AND a.StoreID IN (545)) OR
('545' IS NULL)
)
AND ...
```

The query *appears* to return the exact same results if I change it to:

```
... AND a.StoreID IN (545) AND ...
```

I would appreciate any help with understanding this.

Thanks, in advance!!

Comment: If the `'545'` value was added dynamically from code then this would be a way to optionally filter on that value, or ignore the filter if no value was supplied.

Comment: The `is not null` part is completely unnecessary. `~AB + A` is equivalent to `A + B`.

Comment: It probably works ok though really it doesn't really make sense to test once as a string and again as a numeric value.

Comment: @David, Thanks! Your answer reminded me that I originally lifted this SQL from inside one of the Reports in the Reporting feature of our 3rd-Party software. Please accept my apologies for not remembering to mention that. Again, Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if the value of '545' was passed via a parameter, mostly used in stored procedures or via dynamic SQL generation from an application:

```
(@value IS NOT NULL AND a.StoreID IN (@value)) OR
(@value IS NULL)
```

This kind of clause would do a IN search, if @value is not NULL, or select "all" records, when @value was NULL.

In general, this would conditionally filter the results if a value was supplied

Comment: Thanks! Your answer reminded me that I originally lifted this SQL from inside one of the Reports in the Reporting feature of our 3rd-Party software. Please accept my apologies for not remembering to mention that. Again, Thanks so much!

Comment: np!
if the answer helped you, consider marking it as correct for others with similar questions.